# Plot $f(\lfloor x \rfloor)$ using $f(x)$

Tags: graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

We have plot of $f(x)$. How we can plot $f(\lfloor x \rfloor)$ using geometric ways ?

My try : I think we should draw vertical lines parallel to axis $y$ on integer numbers but What is the next step ?

Comment: What do you mean by "geometric ways"?

Comment: For each interval of the form $[n,n+1)$, your graph will be a horizontal line with $y=f(n)$. So basic idea is to start with the plot of $y=f(x)$, and at integer point draw a horizontal line until the next integer.

Comment: Like drawing lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can mark the points at $f(n)$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and draw the horizontal segments on $[n,n+1)$.

---

The simplest example is given by $f(x)=x$. 
[image]

Comment: I think , I've got it but can you draw a graph for better understanding ?

Comment: @S.H.W: well, consider the example $f(x)=x$ and look at the picture for the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Answer (score 1):

For each integer $x$, calculate $f(x)$ and draw a horizontal line connecting $x$ to $x+1$.